# Any common phrase for "without dying while you try"?

Tags: phrase-request

In Spanish there's a phrase pattern that would translate (literally) as "How to do X without dying while you try" ("*Cómo hacer X sin morir en el intento*").

Is there any similar concept in English? I *feel* I've read something like that, but can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 4):

How to do X without killing yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Word reference.com offers two translations:
[WordReference.com "sin morir en el intento (Spanish-English)](https://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=sin%20morir%20en%20el%20intento)

without perishing in the attempt;
not die trying